# Как расширить тайпинги модуля TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Пишу Websocket-сервер с использованием модуля [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) и использую при этом TypeScript

```
wss.on('connection', ws => { // обработать подключение нового клиента
    ws.on('pong', () => {
        ;(ws as WebSocketWithPing).isAlive = true
        ;(ws as WebSocketWithPing).lastPingpong = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 1000)
        ;(ws as WebSocketWithPing).pingScheduled = true
    })

    ws.on('message', data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Как видно, при понге я пытаюсь присвоить в объект `ws` три переменных и каждый раз мне приходится использовать `as Type` из-за того, что в тайпингах мои кастомные переменные не прописаны. Это выглядит ужасно и я пытаюсь это как-то убрать, но ничего не получается и компилятор постоянно ругается. В самих тайпингах же прописано следующее:

```
declare class WebSocket extends events.EventEmitter {
    on(event: 'ping' | 'pong', listener: (this: WebSocket, data: Buffer) => void): this;
}
```

Поэтому у себя в коде я просто дописал вверху страницы:

```
declare class WebSocket extends EventEmitter {
    isAlive?: boolean;
    lastPingpong?: number;
    pingScheduled?: boolean;
}
```

Но, по-видимому, TypeScript не мерджит две декларации, а просто перезаписывает ту, что в тайпингах - моей. Вопрос: как мне добавить в декларацию три мои кастомные переменные так, чтобы избавиться от необходимости прописывать каждый раз `;(ws as WebSocketWithPing)`, а просто пользоваться `ws`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums) — никак.

> Default exports also cannot be augmented

Я придумал только такой хак:

```
declare class MyWS extends WebSocket {
    isAlive?: boolean;
    lastPingpong?: number;
    pingScheduled?: true;
}

wss.on('connection', (ws: MyWS) => {
    ws.on('pong', () => {
        ws.isAlive = true
        ws.lastPingpong = Math.round(new Date().valueOf() / 1000)
        ws.pingScheduled = true
    })
})
```

Ну и всегда можно хранить данные вне объекта, например в `WeakMap`.